# SEO not showing links to bot safely

Tags: jquery, seo

Is it safe to use jquery to generate links for users and not for bots?

Eg.
I have a PRODUCT LIST page which gets correctly linked from different PRODUCT DETAIL pages.
PRODUCT DETAIL page may be shown with an highlighted feature in this way: `www.site.com/product3?highlight_feature=3`

Now for every list item of the PRODUCT LIST page I want to add all different feature links to the PRODUCT PAGE eg.

```
PRODUCT LIST PAGE
**Product 1** (`www.site.com/product1)
feature1 (www.site.com/product1?highlight_feature=1)
feature2 (www.site.com/product1?highlight_feature=2)
...
```

I do not want the bots to follow features links (because of loss of page rank on PRODUCT LIST PAGE) and I was thinking of using jquery to generate those links. I was thinking to use the same technique for external links, to avoid bots exit from my site. Is it SEO safe? If so, how can I accomplish it?

I was testing something like:

```
$(.myLink).live('click', function(e){
 window.location = ... uri;
});
```

Thanks

Comment: It's been documented that Google is using jQuery to access dynamic content, so your idea probably won't fool the Googlebot.   Just use `robots.txt` for what it was intended.  Also `.live()` has been deprecated in favor of `.on()`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I did not know it's been deprecated! Ok, so what I'm supposed to do to avoid the bot exit from my site towards external links? I have an aggregator site with a lot of external links per product page. I think showing too many links towards a web site may be dangerous for the external site too, besides the bot would exit from my site very easily.

Comment: I'm no SEO expert but until you figure this out, you can block the Googlebot from the site.  I recommend reading all the documentation Google provides to Webmasters about this topic.  I believe that you could include a "no follow" directive on a page-by-page basis within a `meta` tag.  Maybe there's a way you can add this automatically within the target pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to block those feature URLs, you can use robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: highlight_feature
```

This would block URLs like:

- `example.com/product1?highlight_feature=2`
- `example.com/product1?highlight_feature`
- `example.com/highlight_feature=3`
- `example.com/foo/bar/highlight_feature/foo/bar`
- …

---

And/or you can use the `rel` value `canonical`:

For the URL `example.com/product1?highlight_feature=2` add the following `link` element:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/product1" />
```

But you should only use `canonical` if the two pages have nearly the same content, e.g. when the highlight feature really only "highlights" a feature.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know you can disallow links containing a parameter in that way, sounds great. Regards with the canonical link, where am I supposed to put it? In the head or close to the <a hef='example.com/product1'>?

Comment: @Daniele: the `canonical` `link` element needs to placed inside the `head`. See the [documentation](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) from Google.

Answer (score 2):

That's what the [canonical](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) tag is for.

Answer (score 2):

I would add a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) instead, telling bots not to follow those links. It would look something like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /products/
```

Comment: But I do want to index /products/, just I want to avoid that a list page has 1000 links to a single product page.

Comment: Then change `/products/` to the path of your "product list page".

Comment: I want to index product list page too!